# How to play sound after running unit tests in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

When I am developing on my local machine, I want Visual Studio to play a happy sound when I run my unit tests and they pass and a sad sound when one fails and a *really* sad one when more than one fails. How do I do this?

I assume that I need to write a macro, but I can't find any environment events that relate to unit tests. I am using Visual Studio 2010, but it would be nice to have a general solution for most or all versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: On your local machine? Why not let cruise control .net do it for you?

Comment: What UnitTest framework you use? MSTest?

Answer (score 5):

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2019#test-audio-cue), Visual Studio can now play sounds when a test run completes.  It can play one sound if everything passes and another sound if at least one test fails.  It will be available in VS 2019 Update 16.9 Preview 3.  See the section Test Audio Cue on the linked page.

Answer (score 3):

I use a Visual Studio extension called "Ding".  It will let you assign a sound to:  build completed, breakpoint hit, unit test - success, and unit test - failure.

I use only the unit test events with Ding.  I have the "build failed" and "build succeeded" events assigned using the normal Windows program events described by @gerdi above. Ding doesn't differentiate between 1 test failed and many failing.

I don't really find the sounds annoying as I have about 25 projects in my Solution and over 800 unit tests, so I do have a little time to look at other tasks before the sound goes off which is my whole idea for having sounds.  Of course, a short power nap wouldn't be out of the question either (LOL).  And, yes -- I do work alone.

[More info on Ding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VitaliiGanzha.VisualStudioDingextension)

Comment: According to the installer, this no longer works with VS 2017

Answer (score 0):

I am not to sure with unit tests, maybe depending on your extension but you can change the sound for builds in VS in control panel -> sound -> sounds -> program events => there is a sub section for "Microsoft Visual studio" . I had a sound at one stage but it does actually become pretty darn annoying.